# Functions as Namespaces (Eloquent Javascript Book)

Tags: javascript, module, scopes

[from Haverbeke's book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#h_FIe+oM6Cvt):

Consider this trivial module for associating names with day-of-the-week numbers, as returned by a Date object’s getDay method:

```js
var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
function dayName(number) {
  return names[number];
}

console.log(dayName(1));
```

The dayName function is part of the module’s interface, but the names variable is not. We would prefer not to spill it into the global scope.

We can do this:

```js
var dayName = function() {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return function(number) {
    return names[number];
  };
}();

console.log(dayName(3));
```

Ok, but... why do we "need" to return a function? If the aim is to take "names" out of the global scope... can't we just:

```js
var dayName = function(number) {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return names[number];
}

console.log(dayName(3));
```

I think I'm missing something or maybe the book's example is one step further...

Thanks!

Comment: The difference is that in the book's code the variable `names` is created once and reused, and in your alternative the variable is re-created every time the function is called. It doesn't make any difference in a trivial example like this but it might in more complex code (and specifically if the variable needs to keep its value between function calls.)

Comment: Yes! Thanks to point it out.